# Component Resized method is getting called Continously?

Tags: java, swing

```
public class AddImage
{

    public void adjustImageToButton(JButton btn,String imagePath) throws IOException{

        Image master= ImageIO.read(new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(imagePath).getPath()));

        btn.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                super.componentResized(e);
                JButton btn = (JButton) e.getComponent();
                Dimension size = btn.getSize();
                //Insets insets = btn.getInsets();
                //size.width-= insets.left+insets.right;
                //size.height-= insets.top+insets.bottom;
                if(size.width>size.height){
                  //size.width=-1;
                }else{
                   //size.height=-1;
                }
                //System.out.println("size.width"+size.width+"---->"+"size.height"+size.height);
                Image scaled = master.getScaledInstance(size.width, size.height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));

                System.out.println("hellow");
            }
        });
        btn.setBorderPainted(false);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }
}

  public class Main
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        AddImage addImage = new AddImage();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        addImage.adjustImageToButton(button1, "ArrowButton.png");
        addImage.adjustImageToButton(button2, "uparrowbutton.png");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Hi Everyone can anybody explain me why component resize method is getting called continuously ? what is the mistake ? as for my understanding Component resize should be called only when the button get resized. But still without me resizing anything getting called continuously.

Comment: @Ben I can reproduce the issue. My guess is that calling `btn.setIcon()` is causing `componentResized()` to be called again. Could it be because of the image size? I have used pretty big images.

Comment: Okay, now I can reproduce it, I left out the `getScaledInstance` method. So seemingly that one is the culprit then.

Comment: I observed an interesting thing - the `preferredSize()` of the button is 34x10, the image is scaled down to 34x10, but after calling `setIcon()`, the `preferredSize()` of the button becomes 68x20. This triggers the resize, now image is resized to 68x20 and button's preferred size becomes 102x30...

Comment: @ben ok i tested it by commenting, But why is it a reason ? That line just give me the scaled instance doesn't resize the button right ? May be am missing something here i think.

Comment: @JAVA to be honest, I don't know. It's a very weird interaction that I have not seen before.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't fully understand what and why is happening and you would need to investigate it further yourself, but it has to do with preferred size of the button.

Preferred size of a button is affected by multiple things, such as container it is added to, its `LayoutManager`, icon/text of the button and so on.

For some reason, the button's `preferredSize()` is slightly bigger than the scaled image. The initial preferred size is 34x10, but after setting the icon, it changes to 68x20, which causes another resize. Then preferred size after setting an image again (this time image is resized to 68x20), becomes 102x30 and so on. The preferred size is always bigger by 34 in width and 10 in height than the size of the image.

The solution I found was setting the `preferredSize` myself:

```
Image scaled = master.getScaledInstance(size.width, size.height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(scaled);
btn.setIcon(newIcon);
btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(newIcon.getIconWidth(), newIcon.getIconHeight()));
```